# I cannot open my Outlook emails ever since they switched from Hotmail

Tags: outlook.com

Ever since Hotmail was switched to Outlook.com, I could no longer open my emails. The emails are shown there, but it does not open even if I try to open it.

How do I resolve this and resume viewing my email messages now? Do I need to download a program that I wasn't made aware of? If so, is it free? I am currently using Windows Vista.

Comment: OS shouldn't have anything to do with it. What browser (and version) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where I couldn’t open any mail or even open my folders; all I could do was look at the screen. But I did find an answer that worked for me: by resetting *Internet Options* I was able to open everything. I opened *Tools* and went into *Internet Options*, clicked *Advanced* and hit reset. It asks if you want to reset personal settings and I said no and after it was done, I reopened IE and it worked.

Hope this helps.